# using tramp over aws ssm proxycommand

Tags: tramp, ssh

I'm trying to get tramp to use my ProxyCommand from my ~/.ssh/config (pasted below), specifically for AWS SSM. Should I expect this ProxyCommand to work, maybe something is wrong with my environment or how I'm invoking tramp? Or would tramp need changes to its source to support AWS SSM?

I try `C-x C-f /ssh:i-8746484eadb75:/var/log` and it asks me if I want to create the directory or file y/n - never seems to even try connecting to the remote host or looking at my ~/.ssh/config and ProxyCommand.

Any pointers or direction would be most welcome, TIA!

```
Host i-* mi-*
     ProxyCommand sh -c "aws ssm start-session --target %h --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=%p'"
     User ec2-user
```

I'm using emacs 26.3 (9.0) on osx catalina 10.15.3.

Comment: Stuff like `Host i-*` is honored by tramp when connecting to something like `/ssh:i-238427:/`. At least with my emacs 25.x. Maybe it helps to press <tab> on several occassions? What is `AWS SSM` by the way?

Comment: I haven't used aws ever, so I cannot say anything about. However, I would be willing to debug Tramp for this, if somebody provides me a guest account and basic instructions how to use. Note, I'm the Tramp maintainer.

Comment: PS: You could contact me directly via `michael.albinus@gmx.de`

Comment: I'm creating a guest account on a test AWS account, I'll contact you directly over email when I have it working with a set of basic instructions. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the temporary test AWS account, I have been able to access that file system via Tramp. Necessary configs are

1. If you use another AWS profile but `default`, you shall tell it to Emacs. Add to your `~/.emacs`

   ```
   (setenv "AWS_PROFILE" "my_profile")
   ```
2. Add your private key file to `~/.ssh/config`

   ```
   Host i-* mi-*
        ProxyCommand sh -c "aws ssm start-session --target %h --document-name AWStartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=%p'"
        User ec2-user
        StrictHostKeyChecking no
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_aws
   ```

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. For others landing here, the instructions to set up SSH over AWS SSM are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-getting-started-enable-ssh-connections.html. At the risk of stating the obvious, I also had to copy my SSH public key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the host, and for the particular machine I was on I had to edit the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file as described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys.